# Extracting unknown values from XML nodes

Tags: xml, delphi

Can someone help me with getting the "Test Project n" string values from each of these items in `<a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 1"/>`

These do not seem to appear to be attributes. What are they and how do I get the text i need?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
<item Id="814135481" Rank="1"><a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 1"/></item>
<item Id="814135882" Rank="2"><a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 2"/></item>
<item Id="814135908" Rank="3"><a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 3"/></item>
</items>

 RootNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement;
  for I := 0 to RootNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
  begin
   //
  end;
```

RootNode.ChildNodes[I].AttributeNodes[n]

will give me the list of attributes on the item, but I dont know how to extract these values

```
<a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 1"/>
```

XML for understanding ANSWER:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <items>
      <item Id="814135481" Rank="1">
        <a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 1"/>
    </item>
      <item Id="814135882" Rank="2">
        <a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 2"/>
    </item>
      <item Id="814135908" Rank="3">
        <a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 3"/>
    </item>
    </items>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are attributes on the `a` tag, but the `a` tags are children of the `item` tags, which are children of the `items` tag.  Your `for` loop will only give you one result, the `items` node.

You can either process this with nested loops, or you can [use an xpath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511844/delphi-xpath-xml-query) to get a collection of all the tags that match `items/item/a`.  Then you look at the attributes on those.

Comment: i tried a whole series of different RootNode.ChildNodes[x].ChildNodes[y].attributes[z] kinda statements and had no luck :(

Comment: @sholmes: Try the xpath route. If that doesn't work, try "printf debugging": inside your for loops, put a call to `OutputDebugString` (in the `Windows` unit) to get the names of the nodes.  That'll give you a good way to visualize what's going on.  You're probably just missing a step somewhere. :)

Comment: Can you point me to a reference on how those item tags work, When I google search, of course all my returns are about '<" and "/>"  :)

Comment: I dont use printf debugging, but i have a method i do use and I have tried that. You can't debug the nested for loops if you dont know how nested the childnodes are.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was easier than I thought. I was reading the XML wrong:

RootNode.ChildNodes[I].ChildNodes[0].AttributeNodes[1].Text;

Comment: If you have the schema, you could use "XML DataBinding" wizard too.

Comment: @sholmes That's exactly what Mason's answer tells you...you should accept it instead of adding your own answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anywhere in his answer showing what I have as an answer,. I clearly stated that i tried all those options , with the following statement "i tried a whole series of different RootNode.ChildNodes[x].ChildNodes[y].attributes[z] kinda statements and had no luck" - He could have clearly helped me out with the line i have provided. It turns out, I was attempting to use attributes instead of AttributeNodes. Mason wanted me to use "nested loops" or "xpath query"  when i could clearly be done in one line.

Comment: I gave him an upvote, that should count for something. I am not interested in points my self, only answers. I think my answer will help others in the near future. Had I been as vague with my question as he was with his answer, I would have been attacked from all directions with negatives and comments about being more specific. So, why can't someone like I expect that as an answer from experts?

Comment: @sholmes: No reason to be offended. Your solution differs from the original code only by adding another call to `ChildNodes` - and that is exactly what Mason said.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `IXMLDOMDocument` and `XPath`;

```
uses
  msxml;

const
  TestXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' +
            '<items><item Id="814135481" Rank="1">' +
            '<a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 1"/></item>' +
            '<item Id="814135882" Rank="2">' + 
            '<a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 2"/>' + '</item>' +
            '<item Id="814135908" Rank="3">' + 
            '<a n="Formatted Name" v="Test Project 3"/>' + 
            '</item></items>';

var
  Doc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  NodeList: IXMLDOMNodeList;
  ANode: IXMLDOMNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
  Doc.loadXML(TestXML);

  // Select all of the <a> nodes only 
  NodeList := Doc.selectNodes('//a');

  // Error checking omitted. Should test for `NodeList <> nil` before use here.
  for i := 0 to NodeList.length - 1 do
    // Should really use another node here as an intermediate
    //  step, to make sure that getNamedItem succeeded. Omitted
    //  for brevity 
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Node.attributes.getNamedItem('v').nodeValue);
end;
```